# Why am I unable to use na_values in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I don't know why `na_values` is not changing the values with "$-" to NaN. I have manually entered the $- in the file and there are no spaces.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('discounted_products.csv',na_values = ['$-']) 
df.head()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM8ws.png)

Please help here.

Comment: Can you post a few lines of that CSV as text instead of an image please?

Comment: Looks like there was some problem in the Jupyter Notebook. All it took was reopening the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because pandas works with regex by default on string methods (albeit it is not mentioned in the specific [read_csv documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)). Try

```
na_values = [r'$-']
```

---

Update

It worked fine for me

```
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
'''a,b
test,$-'''), na_values=[r'$-'])

print(df)

      a   b
0  test NaN
```

Comment: how about `r'\$-'` ? ... `'$'` is a special character in regex denoting `end of line`